# Content-aware Image Resizing in PHP

Tags: php, ruby, image, resize

I am looking for a open source project that does content-aware image resizing in any of the web back-end language (e.g. PHP, Ruby)

By content-aware image resizing, I mean the one seen in Photoshop CS5, or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qadw0BRKeMk

Thanks.

Comment: I *think* I've seen a PHP implementation of this. The memory is hazy. Maybe try searching for "seam carving"

Answer (score 2):

There is one ImageMagick/PHP based approach [here](http://valokuva.org/?p=99).

This approach involves using ImageMagick's `liquidRescaleImage` function to recognise the important parts of the image and rescale around them

Code sample from site:

```
<?php

/* Create new object */
$im = new Imagick( 'test.jpg' );

/* Scale down */
$im->liquidRescaleImage( 500, 200, 3, 25 );

/* Display */
header( 'Content-Type: image/jpg' );
echo $im;

?>
```

ImageMagick can be easily interfaced from any scripting language. I can't speak to its quality but it looks like it's going in the right direction: It explicitly links to your linked video as a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you have any experience with its performance?

Comment: @felix nope, I've never worked with this, I just came across it some time ago. Generally speaking, ImageMagick is a robust and fast library though, so I'm fairly optimistic it'll work well

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to find anything better than PHPTHumb. http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Does it do content-aware resizing?